# Is there a name for a Satyr like creature with equine features

Tags: mythology

I created a character who is centaur-like. His upper body is completely human however his legs and horse-like and he has two legs. This makes him similar to a Satyr, however, Satyr's have Goat like legs and horns. I haven't found a name for a Two-Legged Centaur and no such creature seems to exist in ancient mythology.

Is there a name for such a creature or alternatively, what could I name it? Centaurs do not exist in my world so I cannot use the term ''Centaur'' as an in-world reference point of naming and I don't want to use the term Centaur at all for this creature because it would fall into the ''Our Centaurs are different'' trope and become an annoyance to my audience.

Any ideas?

Comment: Names are a matter of convention. As such are a matter of opinion.

Comment: A satyr to the ancient Greeks would have been known as a(n) Silenos and would have been thought of as Keith Morrison describes, otherwise chose a name at will, Silenian perhaps to be consistent with mythology but in a modern idiom. As L.Dutch sais, opinion based.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how "_is there a name for this thing_" is opinion based; it isn't a request that someone make up a cool name, after all. Is there a name for a man like creature with goaty legs and horn? Well, yes. That's generally called a "satyr" these days. That's not opinion, that's observation. If there is no name for a similar but more horse-like creature, then the answer is simply "_no_".

Comment: @Starfish Prime "what could I name it?" Can be answered with anything, from ballapaloozajibdab to mightypinkroastedbean, and there is no way to pick the right name, because there is no right one.

Comment: @L.Dutch asking if there is already a name for such a thing is a valid question, because there can be right answers. If there is no such name, then an answer that says "no, pick one yourself" seems entirely valid and non-opinion based. The non-opinion-based question is _right there_. There's no need to laser focus on the one bit you find objectionable and declare that all the rest needs to be thrown away too.

Comment: You do know that the essential attribute of a satyr is that he is perpetually horny and, hmmm, visibly aroused? The buck legs (definitely a buck, never a nanny) are a visual metaphor for sexual prowess (as bucks were reputed to have). A satyr is definitely no something I'd expect to find in a family-friendly story.

Comment: This isn't a family-friendly story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Greek mythology there is the [ipotane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipotane).  For the most part they were overall human-like, but with horse legs, hindquarters, tail, and ears.  Excluding the ears, your creature sounds like an ipotane.

Many [artist renderings](https://www.pinterest.com/erakasun/ipotane/) end up swapping the top and bottom parts, or give ipotanes more horse-like features.  It does seem, however, that the older Greek myths had ipotanes as mostly human except for horse-like legs and tail.  Some reference even refer to them as precursors to centaurs, but I have my doubts about that.  Tracing early Greek mythos is.... complicated.

In any case, here's one random ipotane picture I found (female, but upper body human and lower body horse):

[image: female ipotane]
From [Calleenscrafts](https://twitter.com/Calleenscrafts/status/938385134876848128)

Comment: good answer.  you should cite picture.  credit where due!

Comment: @Willk I'm trying to!  I thought the citation was inserted, but when adding the image I didn't realize the way it passes through to imgur removed the link :/

Comment: Citation needed. (That is to say, I don't believe you that there is such a creature in Greek mythology.) And the completely unsourced Wikipedia article doesn't count. Hint: "ipotane" is impossible as a Greek word or as an English word borrowed from Greek. The closest would be "hippotane" (note the "h" and the double "p"), which would indeed by a perfectly reasonable Englishing of a hypothetical Greek word "hippotanēs"; but I cannot find that hypothetical Greek word anywhere.

Comment: @AlexP The greek alphabet doesn't actually have a letter 'h' (it's reprensent by a certain accent and can only occur on words beginning with a vocal), you're right about the double p though. The wiki article refers to the word [ippotaes](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*i%3Aentry+group%3D24%3Aentry%3Di%28ppo%2Fths1), meaning horse rider, horsemen or knight - if the (ancient) greeks also used that word at some point to refer to a creature like this is probably un-knowable.

Comment: @Nicolai: The Greek spelling system represents a leading "h" by a rough breathing. This has been the convention for two and a half millennia. It is rather late in the day to attempt to change it. And, yes, "hippotēs" (yes, the "h" is absolutely there, in Greek spelling `ἱππότης`, and no, there is no "ae") means "driver or rider of horses" (Liddell and Scott). You cannot make "hippotane" from "hippotēs"; the expected Englishing would be *hippote.

Comment: @AlexP You're close; it's not hippotane but ἱππότης (pronounced "hippotas").  Was often used as "horse people" (that is, people of the horse).  There are some references with this word in the medieval era for knights.  I don't remember when I first studied this, but we're going back some years.  I'll try to dig up a reference when I have more time.

Comment: @cegfault: "Hippotēs" means "driver or rider of horses" (Liddell and Scott). It's not pronounced "hippotas" (but yes, "hippotas" is the form of the word in some dialects.) It's not mythological at all, it is a most pedestrian (ha!) everyday word. And, surprise, "hippotai laoi" or "hippotēs leōs" (literally "horse people") actually means simply the"cavalry" part of an army. Do you or don't you have an authority for the affirmation that there was a creature named "ipotane" in Greek mythology?

Comment: Huh... I never knew about Ipotanes. Strange how I wasn't able to find it through my previous searches. Thanks a lot, m'dude!

Comment: @Hiccaries: You never knew about them because they are not part of Greek mythology; they are a modern invention. This reponse is untruthful. Google ngram viewer cannot even find the word in any of the books in its immense collection.

Comment: @AlexP yeah, I just did some research. The Ipotanes that I could find all have horse heads and they don't fit what I was looking for so I have to keep looking.

Answer (score 6):

Satyrs were originally portrayed as having horselike legs, along with horse ears and tail (and a permanent boner, but that's neither here nor there). They only acquired goatlike characteristics later when they began to be associated and conflated with Pan, which was originally a completely different nature spirit.

Comment: Actually., the permanent sexual arousal is pretty much the *essence* of a satyr.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the tow legged centaurs or satyrs with horse parts Horse-men or Man-horses or Hippandres or Andreshippos or Andrehips, or something like that.